# finding string in txt file and displaying nearest integer

Tags: python, string

I want my code to accept input that is a string (for example: "ABC") and then read through a txt file and find that string; once it finds the string, it should output the closest integer (for example: 456) to the string in the file. Is this possible?

So far, I've found code that can print "related lines," so lines that are 2 lines away from my string. This code is:

```
f = open("textfile.txt", "r")   
searchlines = f.readlines()  
f.close()  
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):  
    if "string" in line:   
        for l in searchlines[i:i+2]: print   
        print
```

This code outputs the two lines in front of and behind my string. But however, I need to print a specific integer, so I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

For my purposes, I need the "closest integer" to the right of the string.

Comment: Yes it is possible but please try to work on the solution first before posting the question.

Comment: What do you mean by closest? On the right or left or which is closer?

Comment: hint: you can use regex `string.*?(\d+)`

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need the minimum input data and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the file into one string with `f.read()` and then get the integer via a regular expression that captures the integer into a group:

```
import re

f = open("textfile.txt", "r")   
content = f.read()  
f.close()

find = 'hello' # the string to find
result = re.search(find + r'\D*(\d+)', content) 

print(result.group(1))
```